# Selenium .NET core 2.2 published project exe not running even on Windows x64

Tags: c#, selenium, publish, specflow, .net-core-2.2

When I build and publish project, the exe generated in the Published folder doesn't Open then closes within a sec. Can anyone help me to resolve the error ?

When I ran the exe from CMD line I am getting this error.

```
cd ..Path_to_Project\WebShopTestAutomation dotnet restore dotnet build dotnet test
```

An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (WebShopTestAutomation.deps.json) has already been found but with a different file extension.

The full project is [here](https://github.com/SavitaMaurya/Selenium-Specflow-project-created-.net-core-2.2/tree/master). Please read the README file to understand and let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is up to you to provide all the necessary information. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out that, in the application's .dps.json file, an entry about the application was present both among the "libraries", like "MyApp" in this example:

```
{
   ...
   "targets": {
      ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0": {
         "MyApp/1.0.0": {           <-- No problem here
            ...
         }
      },
   ...
   "libraries": {
        "MyApp/1.0.0": {            <-- Problem here
           ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Simply removing the entry from "libraries" solved the problem.